# lateinit property pokemon has not been initialized

Tags: android

Could someone help me with this error?

```
class PokemonAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val pokemons: MutableList<PokemonItem> = mutableListOf(),
    var onItemClickListener: (pokemon: PokemonItem) -> Unit = {}
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PokemonAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PokemonAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val viewCriada = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.item_pokemon,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return ViewHolder(viewCriada)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.vincula(pokemons[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = pokemons.size

    fun add(pokemons: List<PokemonItem>) {
        this.pokemons.clear()
        this.pokemons.addAll(pokemons)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        private lateinit var pokemon: PokemonItem
        private val campoNome by lazy { itemView.item_pokemon_nome }
      
        fun vincula(pokemonItem: PokemonItem) {
            this.pokemon = pokemon
            campoNome.text = pokemonItem.nome
        
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it appears you're setting `pokemon` to itself but it has not actually been set yet:

```
fun vincula(pokemonItem: PokemonItem) {
    this.pokemon = pokemon      // < -- This line
    campoNome.text = pokemonItem.nome
}
```

Perhaps you meant this:

```
fun vincula(pokemonItem: PokemonItem) {
    this.pokemon = pokemonItem
    campoNome.text = pokemonItem.nome
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the function vincula

```
this.pokemon = pokemonItem
```